# Object with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an object which contains an array of objects in javascript

```
var alertArray = {
    {threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Agg-02-01', text: 'CPU exceeding policy threshold of 80%', time: '7:00 PM'},
    {threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Leaf-12-22', text: 'Memory utilization exceeding 40%', time: '6:34 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-12', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '5:10 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-11', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '4:32 PM'}
};
```

I dont understand what i am doing wrong,  please help

Comment: What's the issue ?

Comment: On second read, it looks like you need to add square brackets `[` and `]`. What you're probably looking is to specify the inner objects into an array. Just wrap the objects in square brackets and specify a key identifier for the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS objects must have keys.

**You could switch to an array of objects:**

```
var alertArray = [
{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Agg-02-01', text: 'CPU exceeding policy threshold of 80%', time: '7:00 PM'},
{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Leaf-12-22', text: 'Memory utilization exceeding 40%', time: '6:34 PM'},
{threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-12', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '5:10 PM'},
{threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-11', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '4:32 PM'}
];
```

**or give the sub-objects keys:** (making an object of objects)

```
var alertArray = {
o1:{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Agg-02-01', text: 'CPU exceeding policy threshold of 80%', time: '7:00 PM'},
o2:{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Leaf-12-22', text: 'Memory utilization exceeding 40%', time: '6:34 PM'},
o3:{threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-12', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '5:10 PM'},
o4:{threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-11', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '4:32 PM'}
};
```

or if you REALLY DO want an object which contains an array of objects:

```
var alertArray = {
    myObjects: [
    {threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Agg-02-01', text: 'CPU exceeding policy threshold of 80%', time: '7:00 PM'},
    {threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Leaf-12-22', text: 'Memory utilization exceeding 40%', time: '6:34 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-12', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '5:10 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-11', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '4:32 PM'}
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the array-part:

```
var alertArray = {
    someArray: [{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Agg-02-01', text: 'CPU exceeding policy threshold of 80%', time: '7:00 PM'},
    {threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Leaf-12-22', text: 'Memory utilization exceeding 40%', time: '6:34 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-12', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '5:10 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-11', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '4:32 PM'}]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an array you should have used square brackets:

```
var alertArray = [
{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Agg-02-01', text: 'CPU exceeding policy threshold of 80%', time: '7:00 PM'},
{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Leaf-12-22', text: 'Memory utilization exceeding 40%', time: '6:34 PM'},
{threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-12', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '5:10 PM'},
{threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-11', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '4:32 PM'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Array of Objects is something like `[{},{},{},...]`
and Object of array of an objects is something like that `{data:[{},{},{},...]}`

```
var alertArray = {
    data: [{threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Agg-02-01', text: 'CPU exceeding policy threshold of 80%', time: '7:00 PM'},
    {threshold: 'critical', deviceName: 'Device Leaf-12-22', text: 'Memory utilization exceeding 40%', time: '6:34 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-12', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '5:10 PM'},
    {threshold: 'warning', deviceName: 'Leaf10-11', text: 'New Software available for upgrade on device', time: '4:32 PM'}]
};
```